# simultaneous requests in django

Tags: python, django, json-rpc

i have two Django projects. i send/receive data via JSON-RPC between this two projects. my problem is that i started a request in project-1 and call a method in project-2, in the called method of project-2 i call again a method in project-1. my problem is here. it seems i have to terminate a request and then start another one. in fact i want this, when i start calling a method inside projet-2 i want that project-1 request terminated. i want it only for calling not for calling and waiting for response.. how i can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org); looks like the problem may be better suited to its approach (task queue) than what you're doing now. Good luck!